# How do I resolve Run-time Error 438 inside a CATIA macro?

Tags: excel, vba, catia

I am writing a macro in CATIA v5 using VBA. The program is suppose to take points from a geometric set and transfer them into an excel file. I have successfully gotten the excel document open, a header created, but then I receive "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.
      I have tried searching around and it seems like the section of code is trying to interact with something outside of its domain, but I cannot figure out how. Below is a sample of my code. The line that contains "***" to the left is the line that is being pointed out in the debugger.

```
Dim xls As Object
Dim wkbks As Object
Dim wkbk As Object
Dim wksheets As Object
Dim sheet As Object
Dim fs, f, f1, fc, s
Dim coords(2) As Integer
Dim PartDoc

Sub CATMain()

    CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection.Search "CATGmoSearch.Point,all"

    'Function Calls
    AppStart
    CATIAtoXLS

    'wksheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (ExcelFolder & Left(CATIA.ActiveDocument.Name,Len(CATIA.ActiveDocument.Name)-8)&".xls")
    'wksheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub

Private Sub AppStart()

    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xls = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    xls.Application.Visible = True
    Set wkbks = xls.Application.Workbooks
    Set wkbk = wkbks.Add
    Set wksheets = wkbk.Worksheets(1)
    Set sheet = wkbk.Sheets(1)
    sheet.Cells(1, "A") = "X-Cord"
    sheet.Cells(1, "B") = "Y-Cord"
    sheet.Cells(1, "C") = "Z-Cord"

End Sub

Private Sub CATIAtoXLS()

    For i = 1 To CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection.Count
        Set Selection = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection        ***
        Set Element = Selection.Item(i)

        'Transfer data to xls
        Point.GetCoordinates (coords)
        sheet.Cells(i + 1, "A") = coords(0)
        sheet.Cells(i + 1, "B") = coords(1)
        sheet.Cells(i + 1, "C") = coords(2)

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: See [this thread](http://www.coe.org/p/fo/et/thread=14001) from their support forum.

Comment: I don't know CATIA, but an object called `Selection` seems like a bad idea to me. Maybe give it a less ambiguous name - `OSel` perhaps?

Comment: @CLR I don't know CATIA either, but [from what appears to be the documentation](http://catiadoc.free.fr/online/interfaces/interface_Selection.htm), that's not a user defined variable.

Comment: Well it seems changing the name actually fixed that error! Now on the line "Point.GetCoordinates (coords)" it says there is a type mismatch. I attempted declaring coords as a variant, but it did not change anything. EDIT: Got it working. I accidentally deleted a line i didn't mean to!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is that in any method in CATIA VBA which passes an array as an argument, must be called on a object declared variant (explicitly or by default). 
So you it should look like this:

```
Dim px as Variant
Set px = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection.Item(i).Value
Call Point.GetCoordinates(coords)
```

The second problem is that in VBA if you use a subroutine with parentheses, you must use the Call keyword:

```
Call Point.GetCoordinates (coords)
```

Otherwise, you can skip the parentheses and the keyword:

```
Point.GetCoordinates coords
```